# smart field OBJECT type

Tags: forestadmin

I am trying to return an object to a smart field, here is my code ;

```
 varvar  LianaLiana  ==  requirerequire(('forest-express-mongoose''forest-express );

Liana.collection('users', {
  fields: [{
    field: 'feed answer',
   type: 'Object',
    get: function (object) {
      return {1:'text',2:'texrt'};
    }
  }]
});
```

but I am getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Smart Field type can `Boolean`, `Date`, `Enum`, `File`, `Number` or `String`. The type `Object` does not exist.